# javafx and slf4j log4j , application process still running after click on close button

Tags: java, logging, javafx, log4j, slf4j

I have a javafx application and i am using log4j and slf4j for logging.
the problem is that the application doesn't close by clicking on close button i.e. the process is still running.

I have tried to remove the log4j and slf4j, now the application closes correctly and the problem is solved.

I don't know what is the problem of log4j and slf4j? and is there a way to use log4j and slf4j with javafx application?

here is my log4j.xml

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.patients">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value ="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

Comment: Can you take a thread dump using jstack and see what threads are running after you click the close button? Also paste your log4j.xml to have a look.

Comment: i have added log4j.xml

Comment: the log4j.xml looks simple. Nothing to worry. What does the thread dump look like? What the threads with RUNNABLE state after the close button is clicked?

Comment: I just tried with the latest slf4j and log4j and it works just fine. Did you try a minimum application to see if you  got the same problem with it?

Comment: @Lorand do you mean to try a simple application with only log4j ?

Comment: No, a simple javafx application with slf4j and log4j.